# Receiving Files from Apps

Tags: ios, file-sharing

I'm programming an email client and I want to be able to send abritary files as attachment. Therefore I want to receive any file from other Apps.

I looked on many tutorials, but if I want to send a file - i. e. from Photos - to my email client, it doesn't show up as selection.

This is my Info.plist snippet:

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>  
    <array>  
        <dict>  
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>  
            <string>General File</string>  
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>  
            <array>  
                <string>public.data</string>  
            </array>  
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>  
            <string>Alternate</string>  
        </dict>  
    </array>
```

Am I missing something? Do I have to enable any permissions?

PS: I'm testing only in the simulator, because I don't actually have an iPhone or iPad.

Comment: We know it's an iOS question, there is an iOS tag. What was the point of "iOS:"?

Comment: In general, the Photos app doesn't offer the ability to send a photo to other apps. It's not anything you are doing but a lame limitation of the Photos app.